# How to stop div blocking a class

Tags: html, css

My page [here](http://4309.co.uk) is selecting the div element each time it's touched on mobile.

None of `a class` elements are working either and not sure why.

So I have:

```
<div class="designn"><a  
href="https://adsler.co.uk">
design</a></div>
```

Which isn't working as a button/link.

So it seems there may be a relationship to being able to select individual div elements by touch and not being able to select "
`a`. When I try to select `a`, the screen just selects a div element instead, highlighting it and prompting a search bar which asks if I want to copy / past /web search etc.

I want the `a href`to work properly and for my screen to stop selecting div element.

It seems that the div block is covering the a class. How to stop that?

Css:

```
.d {font-size: 610px; position: relative; bottom: 750px; 
right: 170px; color: #e6f7ff;}

.e {font-size: 500px; position: relative; bottom: 700px; left: 
100px; color: red; opacity: 0.2}

.s {font-size: 610px; position: relative; bottom: 400px; left: 
5px; color: #e6f7ff;}

.i {font-size: 500px; position: relative; bottom: 400px; left: 
200px; color: red; opacity: 0.2}

.g {font-size: 610px; position: relative; bottom: 150px; 
right: 170px; color: #e6f7ff;}

.n {font-size: 500px; position: relative; bottom: 150px; left: 
100px; color: red; opacity: 0.2}

.designn {color: black; font-size: 12px;}
```

So this html:

```
<div class="d">d</div>
<div class="e">e</div>
<div class="s">s</div>
<div class="i">i</div>
<div class="g">g</div>
<div class="n">n</div>
```

Is covering and blocking selection of this a class html:

```
<div class="designn"><a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk">design</a></div>
```

In layman's terms, the letters `DESIGN` seem to be stopping me being able to click on the links on the homepage.

Comment: You don't have any content in them firstly, also please post css

Comment: There is no context to how it fits together, please make it more clear and stucture as it is on the site

Answer (score 0):

u can use css attribute **touch-action**
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: Thanks but how will that solve my issue? I need to a class to the front, as it were?

Comment: can u put ur real html on site... where i can to view it?